# Does it make sense to use UE4 for quick-prototyping, Unity3d - for real multiplatform deployment?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, unreal-engine4

I'd like to create an interesting mobile game (I hope it will be really ineresting). There are two best tools on the markeT: UE4 and Unity3d.
UE4 has an attractive interface. This interface is very intuitive to understanding. Blueprints are also very intuitive to understanding. But, UE4 is totally not ready for multiplatform's development: Android's support is VERY bad :(

Unity3d is much hard to understand, Unity3d requires much stronger programming's skills, iterface is ugly, not intuitive  etc. But Unity3d is really works on almost every mobile platform and for almost every mobile device on the market.

so, does it make sense to  "play" with game's prototype in UE4, quickly create and test main logic (Blueprints are great and easy to use), then, after I'll sure my idea is really interesting & attractive for players,  move art assets to Unity3d, coding Blueprints's logic in C# etc???

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Better place to ask this would be Unity or UE4 forums.

Comment: @RayGarner http://gamedev.stackexchange.com would be a good place too

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Unity3d is much hard to understand, Unity3d requires much stronger
>   programming's skills, iterface is ugly, not intuitive etc.

Thats like YOUR opinion man.
MY OPINION is that UE4 interface is bloated and slow and unity's has just what you need and no more.   Both are infinitely modifiable so either one can be fit to suit almost anyone's needs.
So not a good reason to choose.

> so, does it make sense to "play" with game's prototype in UE4, quickly
>   create and test main logic (Blueprints are great and easy to use),
>   then, after I'll sure my idea is really interesting & attractive for
>   players, move art assets to Unity3d, coding Blueprints's logic in C#
>   etc???

So this all depends on who you are but in general if your not much of a programmer than sure it makes sense to use the excellent UE4 blueprint system.  There are solid visual scripting tools in Unity that you can buy though.  So thats not really a good reason to decide on which engine to use for prototyping.

I dont see any reason if you prototype out your game in blueprints to switch back over to unity.  If you went through all that trouble to learn UE4 and the blueprint system.  Just build your game that way.  Same goes if you prototype your game in unity.

> But, UE4 is totally not ready for multiplatform's development:
>   Android's support is VERY bad :(

Sir/Bro... at the speed at which UE4 is churning out new features by the time you even get halfway done with your prototype my guess is android support will be pristine. (dont hold me to that just a guess)

Ok so if you are just wanting to make a game thats my answer for you ... HOWEVER if you are going to be or have plans to be a programmer my alternate advice is whichever you choose do not use any visual scripting period.  Learn the ways of your craft by doing and learning from others.

If your  end goal is to become a programmer and you want the easier start go for unity C#.  C#  is a bit easier to get into and the iteration times on unity are next to nothing. 
If you have a  bit more time on your hands and want to get nitty gritty go with c++ UE4... or go all the way and build a game from scratch c++.

Comment: -1 because opinion-based questions and answers are off-topic on SO

Comment: Because I totally deserved that thanks

Comment: Not you, the answer deserves a downvote. It actually starts with "your opinion, my opinion", that's essentially the definition of an opinion-based Q&A. FWIW I also -1 and voted to close the question - which will likely happen within hours.

Comment: No arguments there but down voting a helpful answer is not helpful to anyone.  Next time ill be sure to tell them to bug off or just ignore them.  I am just now getting around to answering peoples questions so still new to it.

Comment: The thing is, within the guidelines of SO the above answer is not deemed helpful. The "learn to program" suggestions I understand and can be seen helpful advice but should be made as a comment since they don't answer the question (definitively).

Comment: thanks @Ray Garner. Until Unity 5 I'll try to "play" with UE4. Then, may be I'll migrate to Unity.
Reason: I want to quickly check valueable of my idea. May be it worth nothing for players (at least, I want to test it on my friends, relatives, etc)